# django chat application using redis - how/where do I "listen" to messages after subscribing?

Tags: django, chat, real-time, redis

So I am trying to write a chat system using django (I am relatively new to real time system). 
I did some research - there are lots of options (twisted, tornado etc) but for now I decided to to try and use nginx as the web server and redis's pubsub.

The chat would be between two users at a time.

Following is what I was thinking of:

1. On authentication all users issue a psubscribe chatctrl:*:. This essentially subscribes to a control channel to establish the initial conversation that is always needed
2. When a user u1 launches a chat with user u2, we
3. create a channel, say "chat:u1:u2" and subscribe to it.
4. The user u1 publishes a message to the control channel chatctrl:u1:u2: (a control message that would be listened to by u2) says effectively "do you want to chat with me on channel "chat:u1:u2"?
5. The user u2 should get this message, subscribes to the channel and responds as yes via another message on control channel (or on the newly established channel.
6. A session is established and both users can publish to the same channel and listen to it as well.

My question is:
1. Does the above make sense, first of all? If not how would you do it using redis?
2. The second question is where do I put the loop to listen to the messages. Since it would be "blocking" when there are no messages, it can not go in a view or in a model accessed by a view. Should it be in a spawned thread and if so how do I unsubscribe once the chat session is over?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614274/need-help-understanding-comet-in-python-with-django/12356964#12356964) for an example of the system you describe.

In that code, the view spawns a Gevent greenlet that subscribes to Redis and pushes messages out to the client browser over socket.io.

The view then blocks until a message is recieved over socket.io, repeating for the duration of the chat session.

Hope that helps!