# how to combine django plus gevent the basics?

Tags: python, django, comet, gevent

After much searching and googling I am coming back to the well.
I have Django 1.4 and am looking for a decent *working* example to figure out getting Django to work with gevent.
I like the Django framwork but I need it to handle long polling.
I already have a working server using gevent on it's own that handles long polling requests as well as does image streaming via http at about 10 frames/second. I would like to use all the goodies in Django to provide a framework for this part.

There are many examples out there, but unfortunately none of these seem to work out of the box! It would really help to have a working example to understand how these two things are working together.

Here is what I have found so far and the problems:

http://codysoyland.com/2011/feb/6/evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent/
problem:
ImportError: Could not import settings 'webchat.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named webchat.settings

https://github.com/codysoyland/django-socketio-example/blob/master/README.rst
Problem: installation fails with permission problem getting gevent
Tried manually getting it from git hub. The example runs, but generates these errors when the browsers connect.

These are informative but do not provide the basic answer.
[Need help understanding Comet in Python (with Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614274/need-help-understanding-comet-in-python-with-django)
https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/tip/examples/webchat/chat/views.py
http://blog.gevent.org/2009/10/10/simpler-long-polling-with-django-and-gevent/

What I hope someone can explain (please, pretty please....) is this:
I have a basic site created using Django 1.4 - the tutorial here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/ is excellent.
So now I need to understand what changes to make in order to use gevent and be able to handle asynchronous events. I am sure it is not difficult - I just need someone who understands it to explain what to do and also what is happening (with things like monkey_patch).

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's how I run Django with gevent + monkey patching:

1. I've modified `manage.py` so the first line (after the shebang) is `from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()`
2. I've added a new `run_production_server` script (see below).

Finally, I've configured my front-end webserver to proxy requests to port `1234` (the port which `run_production_server` is listening on).

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer

from django.core.management import setup_environ    
import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler as DjangoWSGIApp
application = DjangoWSGIApp()
server = WSGIServer(("127.0.0.1", 1234), application)
print "Starting server on http://127.0.0.1:1234"
server.serve_forever()
```

Some might complain that this server isn't "web scale" enough. I doubt they would be able to provide benchmarks to prove that, but if you're worried you could also use `gunicorn` or `uwsgi` for your server. But this works just fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for the script, that is a big help. But, I have tried this and I think I am missing something. I am starting with the default django 1.4 project. I am starting the server with %python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000. How do I use the script you provided?

Comment: What part of its use are you unsure of?

Comment: Sorry to ask dumb questions.... how do I get this script to run when I start things up using manage.py? I am looking at the django wsgi docs right now and it mentions wsgi.py - is this where your script should go?

Comment: When I run the script above I get this     raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)

So I added this: from django.conf import settings
Now I get this: ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

Comment: I have no replaced wsgi.py with the contents of this script and I get this now: AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: Oh, wait, I might have mixed up the order of the imports. I've edited my answer, give that a try. Put it in a file then run it. It will start an HTTP server listening on port 1234.

Comment: Make sure to check that your database connector supports running asynchronous inside gevent. For instance https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python does not.