# Options to write a Python Server that will check database consitently for updates and changes

Tags: python, database, sql-server-2008, client, twisted

I am a self taught Python programmer and I have an idea for a project that I'd like to use to better my understanding of Socket programming and networking in general.  I was hoping that someone would be able to tell me if I am on the right path, or point me in another direction.
The general idea is to be able to update a database via a website UI, then a Python Server would then be consistently checking that database for changes. If it notices changes it would then hand out a set of instructions to the first available connected client.

The objective is to
A - Create a server that reads from a database.
B - Create clients that connect to said server from a remote machine.
C - The server would then consistently read the database and and look for changes, for instance a column that is a Boolean that would signify Run/Don't run. 
D - If say the run Boolean is true, the server than would hand the instructions off to the first available client.
E - The client itself would then handle updating the database of certain runtime occurrences
Questions/Concerns
A - My first concern is the resources it would take to be constantly reading the database and searching for changes. Is there a better way of doing this? Or Could I write a loop to do this and not worry much about it?
B - I have been reading the documentation/tutorials on Twisted and at this moment this looks like a viable option to be able to handle the connections of multiple clients (20-30 for arguments sake). From what I've read Threading looks to be more of a hassle than it's worth.
Am I on the right track? Any suggestions? Or reading material worth looking at?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Whatever way you want to do it, since you are just starting on it I would recommend not to worry about performance. Just implement the best solution you can figure out.

Comment: Twisted will get you twisted up, not unlike the [cover of its book](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Qqr380niL._SL500_AA300_.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The [Django web framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/) implements something called [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) which at the [ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/) level lets you detect changes to specific database objects and attach handlers to those changes. Since it is an open source project, you might want to [check the source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/dispatch) to understand how Django does it while supporting multiple database backends (Mysql, postgres, oracle, sqlite).

If you directly want to listen to database changes then most databases have some kind of a system that logs every transactional change. For example [MySql has the binary log](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/article.php/3903646/Inside-MySQL-Binary-Logs.htm) you can keep reading from to detect changes to the database.

Also while Twisted is great I would recommend you use [Gevent/Greenlet](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html) + [this](http://sdiehl.github.com/gevent-tutorial/). If you want to integrate with Django, [how to combine django plus gevent the basics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964571/how-to-combine-django-plus-gevent-the-basics) would help

Comment: [sqlalchemy provides Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/event.html) if it is used to work with a database.