# Can django integration zerorpc?

Tags: django, zerorpc

I'm intending to use rpc in my django project.And I found zerorpc is a beautiful lib for rpc.So I want to intrgration django with zerorpc.
What is the best practice? And how to start the zerorpc server in production?Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you are running Django with Gevent and you understand the implication of using Gevent, because zerorpc requires it.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.I had learned Gevent just now.So can you give me some advise about how to integration this two?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964571/how-to-combine-django-plus-gevent-the-basics