# Is there a way to change TCP settings for Django project?

Tags: python, django, tcp

I have been working on a project built with Django. When I run profiler due to slowness of a page in project, this was a line of the result:

> 10    0.503    0.050    0.503    0.050 {method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects}

Which says almost 99% of passed time was for the method recv_into(). After some research, I learned the reason is Nagel's algorithm which targets to send packets only when the buffer is full or there are no more packets to transmit. I know I have to disable this algorithm and use TCP_NODELAY but I don't know how, also it should only affect this Django project.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you exactly profile? Are you using the development server?

Comment: I have profiled a specific method in which data from database(using mongoengine) is being processed. I am not using the development server. The ones in use are: Python, Django, mongoengine and REST framework.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but TCP_DELAY is only relevant when there are many small packets going back and forth, as in the case of a distributed game server etc. I take it that mongodb responses would be relatively bigger, so I don't think there will be a major (if any) performance gain here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try the way you suggested to see if there's any performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of django settings.I think you can do this at

**load balancer(nginx) level** rather than django, under http directive.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#tcp_nodelay

**At uwsgi level:**

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#tcp-nodelay

Answer (score 0):

Use [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/djangofastcgi/) as a proxy and into the configuration you can set in the http block

```
http{
  #...
  tcp_nodelay   off;
  #...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "gevent" , This can help us a little by improving socket performance by using cooperative threads.

Here below is the thread which will help you to combine Django and gevent , Which can give just the basics

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer

from django.core.management import setup_environ    
import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler as DjangoWSGIApp
application = DjangoWSGIApp()
server = WSGIServer(("127.0.0.1", 1234), application)
print "Starting server on http://127.0.0.1:1234"
server.serve_forever()
```

Source :

[how to combine django plus gevent the basics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964571/how-to-combine-django-plus-gevent-the-basics)

http://www.gevent.org/

Answer (score -1):

Are you using cache settings in the settings.py file? Please check that maybe you have tcp_nodelay enable there, if so then remove it or try to clear browser cache.

Comment: Thanks for your time for answering the question. There is nothing about caching in settings.py, so I don't think this is the answer.